# Unable to fetch more than 100 tweets using Twython

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twython

I have the following script:

```
twitter=Twython(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
tags=['#pc', #computer', '#technology']
for tag in tags:
    try:
        search_results=twitter.search(q=tag, count=200)
    except TwythonError as error:
        print error
        sys.exit()
    for tweet in search_results['statuses']:
        user = tweet['user']['screen_name'].encode('utf-8')
        print user
```

But when I omit count or change it to 300 it shows me for each tag only 100 results.
How can I change it to unlimit results?

[Methods in tweepy module is welcome as well]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter API returns a maximum number of 100 tweets per request. Read Twitter APIs [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets).

To fetch more than 100 tweets you'll have to send more than one request and need to understand how Twitter timeline works. Check out this [link](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/timelines).

Anyways, what you need to do is make use of the `max_id` variable. `max_id` is basically the id of the last tweet that you've fetched.